How does a Recursive CTE know to only process records added during the last iteration (and not looking at all of them)?
Consider this [v good] example from Using recursive CTE to generate a range of data
WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (
  SELECT '2023-01-01'::timestamp  AS date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date + interval '1 day'
  FROM date_range
  WHERE date < '2023-12-31'
)
SELECT *
FROM date_range;

I can understand how to create this query, but do not understand the underlying logic/rules executed by the database engine.  Specifically: for the select date + 'interval 1 day' from date_range: how does it know to only "consider" the very last added record [instead of taking all the previously added records and adding 1 to each of them]?
To illustrate more clearly: consider when we are at 2023-01-03 in the recursion. In that case we already presumably have 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02, and 2023-01-03 in the table. Why does the second query shown below not "find" three records and add 1 to all of those 3 records?
  SELECT date + interval '1 day'
  FROM date_range
  WHERE date < '2023-12-31'

Instead what is happening is the engine only "finds" the very last record. 2023-01-03 and adds one to that to generate the single new record 2023-01-04?  Is that just something I take on "faith" for recursive views?

It only looks at the previous record because that’s how recursive CTE statements are coded to work in the DBMS; if they didn’t do that then recursive CTEs wouldn’t work. You take it on faith no more than you would that any other piece of functionality in the DBMS works as documented; do you have the same concerns about joins or filters or any of the functions the DBMS provides?

Don't take faith on that. That's how it actually works. The PostgreSQL docs have a great explanation about that.

please read the manual about cte  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Are you asking: is it certainly the case (ie documented) to do so, or are you asking: how is it possible for the engine to have such an algorithm that can actually do this?

@Charlieface  This is a crucial new feature [to me] that I would like to understand as well as possible.  The specifics that were noted in another commenter (nbk) and helpful to me are included in an answer I added.

You didn't answer my question: what are you actually asking?

Please do not use [] characters in the title unless absolutely necessary. Those characters are used for closed and duplicate questions, and their presence can be confusing. You can read more about using them in [ask], specifically the section on writing titles. Also, in this case they aren't appropriate - the parentheses I replaced them with are more suitable.


consider when we are at 2023-01-03 in the recursion. In that case we already presumably have 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02, and 2023-01-03 in the table. Why does the second query shown below not "find" three records and add 1 to all of those 3 records

Because there are 3 different tables (tuplestores) involved. Results keep getting accumulated and that's where the 2023-01-01, 2023-01-02, and 2023-01-03 live - the query doesn't target that. Instead it targets work_table which gets wiped and replaced with contents of intermediate_table from previous iteration - at that point it only holds 2023-01-03:



iteration
work_table
intermediate_table
results




1
('2023-01-01')non-recursive term
('2023-01-01'+interval '1 day')
('2023-01-01'), ('2023-01-02')


2
('2023-01-02')previous values from intermediate
('2023-01-02'+interval '1 day')
('2023-01-01'), ('2023-01-02'), ('2023-01-03')


3
('2023-01-03')previous values from intermediate
('2023-01-03'+interval '1 day')
('2023-01-01'), ('2023-01-02'), ('2023-01-03'), ('2023-01-04')



Behaviour above illustrates the description from the doc:


Evaluate the non-recursive term. (...) Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary working table.

So long as the working table is not empty, repeat these steps:
a) Evaluate the recursive term, substituting the current contents of the working table for the recursive self-reference. (...) Include all remaining rows in the result of the recursive query, and also place them in a temporary intermediate table.
b) Replace the contents of the working table with the contents of the intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table



The same description in src/backend/executor/nodeRecursiveunion.c responsible for the feature, sounds a bit more cryptic:
 * 1. evaluate non recursive term and assign the result to RT    //ok
 *
 * 2. execute recursive terms                                    //ok
 *
 * 2.1 WT := RT                                                  //ok
 * 2.2 while WT is not empty repeat 2.3 to 2.6. if WT is empty returns RT
 * 2.3 replace the name of recursive term with WT
 * 2.4 evaluate the recursive term and store into WT
 * 2.5 append WT to RT
 * 2.6 go back to 2.2

But the code really does what it said on the tin, how it said it. Here's the 2.2, 2.3, 2.6 part, even matching the names from the doc:
    /* 2. Execute recursive term */
    for (;;)
    {
        slot = ExecProcNode(innerPlan);
        if (TupIsNull(slot))
        {
            /* Done if there's nothing in the intermediate table */
            if (node->intermediate_empty)
                break;

            /* done with old working table ... */
            tuplestore_end(node->working_table);

            /* intermediate table becomes working table */
            node->working_table = node->intermediate_table;

            /* create new empty intermediate table */
            node->intermediate_table = tuplestore_begin_heap(false, false,
                                                             work_mem);
            node->intermediate_empty = true;

            /* reset the recursive term */
            innerPlan->chgParam = bms_add_member(innerPlan->chgParam,
                                                 plan->wtParam);

            /* and continue fetching from recursive term */
            continue;
        }


If you think about it, the "taking all the previously added records and adding 1 to each of them" thing is exactly what it does. All added previously, as in previous iteration, not all processed since the beginning of operation. In your case, it started with a single row, so in each iteration all previously added records amount to 1. If you started with 2, you'd get 2 at a time, for as long as both match the WHERE condition.

Yes, the working table being replaced is the key aspect - as mentioned in the link provided by another commentator and described in my answer as well.

@WestCoastProjects Yup, I saw. I was writing it in parts, so it was doomed to arrive late to the party and sound duplicative - if you don't mind, I'll just leave it up.

you put nice effort in here, i'll award

From the link noted by @nbk postgresql Recursive Queries: the key step is this:

Replace the contents of the working table with the contents of the intermediate table, then empty the intermediate table.

So for the query mentioned in the question the intermediate table would apparently be only the newly generated result [and not any others previously  generated by the recursion].

The recursion means calling a peace of code from the same peace of code. The most important thing regarding recursions is to define how and when to escape from it. It's done here with the WHERE clause. Make sure, if you use any kind of recursions, to define a safe exit first to avoid indefinite loops.

a recursive cte is one peace of code that generates a set of rows. It has two parts that are unioned to give a complete resultset. But it is still one code declaring a cte. The delaration starts with:

WITH RECURSIVE date_range AS (


first part (the fixed part) in your example doesn't change the results through recursion steps - it gives you a starting point with just that 1 row

SELECT '2023-01-01'::timestamp  AS date
/*
date
-------------------
2023-01-01 00:00:00


the second part uses union to add another row and checks is it the right time for safe escape from the recursion

UNION ALL
SELECT date + interval '1 day'
  FROM date_range
  WHERE date < '2023-01-04'    -- safe escape when date is < '2023-01-04'
/* 1st pass result
date
-------------------
2023-01-01 00:00:00     -- row from the first part ( read no. 2. )
2023-01-02 00:00:00     -- this is the value of date column at the moment


If it is not time to exit the recursion the code as a whole calls itself to do the union part again and check if it is time to escape

/* 2nd pass
date
-------------------
2023-01-01 00:00:00     -- row from the first part ( read no. 2. )
2023-01-02 00:00:00     -- a row from the first pass union
2023-01-03 00:00:00     -- this is the value of date column at the moment


that repeats until the escape condition is true - false is - get out of this right now ....

